# Uploading images from FLASH in CakePHP

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash, cakephp

I'm having trouble handling my images created from my flash application, it sends the data via raw post data, and it's writing the image to my /webroot folder.

Here's the php code I have in an "AvatarController.php" file.

```
public function uploadImage()
{
    $this->autoRender = false; // no view file

    if ($this->request->is('post')) // if post data
    {
        $aUser = $this->aCurrentUser(); // gets user info

        if ( isset ( $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"] )) // gets raw post data
        {
            $sImgName = $aUser['User']['username'] . '_full' . '.png';

            $fp = fopen($sImgName, "wb");
            fwrite( $fp, $GLOBALS[ 'HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA' ] );
            fclose( $fp );
        }

    }
}
```

what I'm having trouble with is saving this into a different folder e.g. /webroot/avatars, and how would I go about resizing the image, ultimately what I want to do is have three or so sizes, so for example "Username_full", "Username_80", "Username_50"; so the full size, 80% smaller, 50% smaller, etc.

I've just never handled uploads like this, from flash.

Any help, suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.kavoir.com/2009/01/php-resize-image-and-store-to-file.html

This looks like a decent tutorial on the resize/move business PHP.  The other part with regard to grabbing the file itself, see this post, http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?360502-AS3-PHP-File-Upload what you're doing may work but I just tend to use the $_FILES variable as it's clear to me what's going to be in there.

Comment: Thanks, I would have used $_FILES too but again, I'm sending the ByteArray to PHP and I don't know if that's entirely possible!

Comment: ah I see what you're saying now, wasn't entirely following that, so have you tried just using the file you generated up there in your PHP and passing it through the script I linked here, so long as gd is available this should be doable and allow you to achieve your goal of the multi-resolution images.

Comment: Also I failed to mention here the byte data would have to be encoded in some sort of format that will be "understood" by gd.  You can do this on the AS3 side by encoding into JPEG at least http://blog.six4rty.ch/2010/07/17/as3-quickhint-convert-bitmapdata-to-bytearray/  Also on a side note, you should accept answers or work through to get a resolution on your other questions, or if you found an answer post it and accept, or close the questions if they're found to not be relevant.  Otherwise it ruins your history on SO.  People will be less likely to help.